# ReportLab render right border for table cells?

Tags: border, reportlab

There are LINEBELOW and LINEABOVE in the reportlab documentation.
But i can't find a way do define right or left borders (LINELEFT,LINERIGHT).

Any suggestion how to render cells with right border only?

**Edit:**

I discovered 'INNERGRID' which allows me to put a border between two cells:

```
('INNERGRID',(0,0),(1,0),0.3*mm,(0,0,0))
```

This will renders a black border between the 1st and 2nd cell of the 1st row:

```
┌───────╥───────┐
│ cell1 ║ cell2 │    ║ = Border
└───────╨───────┘    │ = cell
```

But what I'm looking for is something like:

```
╓───────┬───────╖
║ cell1 │ cell2 ║
╙───────┴───────╜
```

Answer (score 4):

There are `'LINEBEFORE'` <- left border, and `'LINEAFTER'` <- right border, for this objective in **ReportLab**.

Documentation here: https://docs.reportlab.com/reportlab/userguide/ch7_tables/ in the section called "TableStyle Line Commands".

Answer (score -1):

I do not believe there is currently support for setting the right border independently exposed by `TableStyles`. However, based on what you editing your question to add, you should be able to get what you want with something like this:

```
('GRID',(0,0),(-1,-1),0.3*mm,(0,0,0)),
('BOX',(0,0),(-1,-1),0.6*mm,(0,0,0))
```

That should be a thin grid between the cells and then a thicker border around the table.